# Android Video Streaming Problem

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am new to android and trying to streaming video from my server.
When i run the application it gives Error "sorry,this video is not valid for streaming to this Device.." than i download and push to sdcard of my device(samsung Galaxy 5)this time video is playing.... i convert this video by SOTHINK VIDEO CONVERTER..
Any Help??

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

We ran into exactly the same problem, and I found a solution at this link:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9044

In short, if you have access to a Mac, you can encode the videos using HandBrake.  Be sure to check the "Web optimized" checkbox.  I'm encoding as format:MP4 file, Video Codec: H.264.  After I did this and uploaded I was able to view the videos (or at least listen to them) in a 2.1 simulator, which had been giving that exact warning message before.  I have not been able to get a hold of an actual 2.1 device, but I suspect it will work.  When I confirm that I'll check back in here to let you know.

Comment: Ah, forgot to check back in, but yes this did work for me.  And thanks for the up vote!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are talking about sothink video encoder engine. Actually this program only supports the apple devices in ios system, for example, iphone, ipad and ipod.

Here is the official product homepage of sothink video encoder engine, and hope it helps!
http://www.sothinkmedia.com/flash-video-encoder-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

The only issue for error "sorry,this video is not valid for streaming to this Device.." is that there is some problem in video format. Just correct the format/codec of mp4 and then it would run gracfully.