# Android videoView gives me Alert "Sorry,This video cannot be played"?

Tags: android

```
My Code::

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri
                .parse("www.logisticinfotech.com/client/Malasiya Cup/movie.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();

    }
```

Error::Sorry,This video cannot be played.

Logcat::

```
01-03 20:19:14.044: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(454): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
01-03 20:19:14.044: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(454): CheckJNI is ON
01-03 20:19:14.224: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(454): --- registering native functions ---
01-03 20:19:14.874: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.logistic.videoview/.MainActivity }
01-03 20:19:15.014: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(454): Shutting down VM
01-03 20:19:15.044: DEBUG/dalvikvm(454): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-03 20:19:15.134: INFO/AndroidRuntime(454): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-03 20:19:15.784: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('www.logisticinfotech.com/client/Malasiya Cup/movie.mp4')
01-03 20:19:15.805: ERROR/MediaPlayer(420): error (1, -2147483648)
01-03 20:19:15.834: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.logistic.videoview/.MainActivity: 821 ms (total 821 ms)
01-03 20:19:15.885: ERROR/MediaPlayer(420): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-03 20:19:15.885: DEBUG/VideoView(420): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you have a look at Android's overview of supported media formats. This site covers everything from the first versions of Android to the latest:

[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

I'm guessing you're trying to include a video in your application, and that it needs to work on all devices, so I'd suggest you go ahead and try to encode a video with a profile similar to the `SD (High quality)` listed on the above mentioned site.

There are plenty of free video converters available that you can use for encoding the video - one of them could be [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/).

Comment: How I can convert if I want play streaming video?

Answer (score 1):

To expand further on my comment, I had fought a lot with different encodings/formats/etc until I got the one that worked on all android devices (at least all that I tested).  Using ffmpeg, here's what finally worked:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i inputfile.ext -y -s 320x240 -vcodec libx264 -vpre medium -vpre baseline -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

Comment: I fallowed the steps from here : http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html . Everything seemed to work fine, but now when I use the command given by you, it says: Unknown encoder 'libx264' .what to do?

Comment: What operating system are you using ffmpeg on?  If it's windows it may be 'x264' (without the 'lib').  Otherwise you may have an incomplete installation of ffmpeg.  Run `ffmpeg -codecs` to see if x264 codec is installed.

Comment: I'm using mac os. On ffmpeg -codecs run , i have in the list : D V D  h264            H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 .

Comment: That's your issue.  You don't have the x264 encoder installed.  My mac osx can run this command with no problem - and my line contains `  EV    libx264         libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10`  Try recompiling the ffmpeg, running `configure` with `./configure --enable-shared --disable-mmx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-zlib --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --enable-libtheora --arch=x86_64`

Comment: I'll try that , and be back to tell if it worked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AleksG What you do for play video in videoview?

Comment: @Samir My playback code is pretty much the same as in the original question

Comment: What should i do for remove this alert and play video?

Comment: it seems I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. I've done it all over again , and at command ./configure --enable-shared --disable-mmx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-zlib --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --arch=x86_64
I have this error : ERROR: libx264 not found

Comment: x264 is an external library depencency, you need to build/install it separately before compiling ffmpeg - have a look at this page: http://www.martinlos.com/?p=41 - specifically, search for 'x264'.  While there, you may want to check other optional dependencies.

Comment: ok I have installed x264 , it sais successfully in usr/bin. but when I give the command you gave , it still says unknown x264. Do you happen to have a link to a good tutorial for installing ffmpeg?  I believe it's something wrong with the paths :(

Comment: I myself used the page I gave you as a reference - and it seems to work, try following those steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem , I just figured out that it cames from the video format and encoding. But I didn't really fing the combination thet works on all devices.

thanks for give the answer if you find it!

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022072/android-video-streaming-problem

Comment: hello Samir, this is my issue to. I don't know how to encode my video to work , that's why I'm trying this thing with ffmpeg. (I've just gave you the link that helped me somehow to clear things in my mind)

Answer (score 0):

i had d same issue 
and i resolved by adding a delay of 250ms. actually the error occurs when we try to capture and play immediately. At that time, the engine is not yet ready to play (coz it hasnt reached End of streami.e. hasnt read the video completely)