# video doesn't play with VideoView while play's with native player

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, native

Here is my code. In this if I launch the intent with video url it play's while it doesn't play's in videoview is there any way to get it working in VideoView

```
VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
String videoURL = "video_url";
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURL));

setContentView(mVideoView);
```

while this native player plays video

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent();
theIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoURL), "video/*");
```

I tested this on device also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below way

```
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            // Set video link (mp4 format )
            Uri video = Uri.parse("mp4 video link");
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.start();
```

Refer this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6410421/1441666

And also check supported formats [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714189/1441666

Comment: mVideoView.start(); not needed to call
 problem is its giving the error "sorry video can not be played"

Comment: my file is valid 3gp file & it play's with native player

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be helpfull.

```
VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);

MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setMediaPlayer(view);
view.setMediaController(mc);
try{
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(file_path));
} catch(){
}
view.requestFocus();
try{
    view.start();   
}catch(){
}
```